# Manga: Special abilities come from crests around the body. The male main character get his arms cut off effectively rendering his ability useless

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic

This manga I read has a word of magic and a crest that every one show that you have a ability a boy thats the last of some clan he has crest on both his palms after a fight in competition for prize money a leader of sorts spot his crest and recognizes it as a clan that was the strongest betrayed and destroyed an assassin is sent to kill him and erase all evidence and fights there are more clans that were jealous of this clan so they eradicated them the sus guy fights the boy and cut his arms off showing him mercy in cuttin his arms off he can no longer use his powerful abilitys and gets prosthetics

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Black and white

Comment: K I’m new thanks for the correction